# Android music player that can shuffle albums?

Tags: android, music

I'm looking for an Android music player that shuffle albums. That is, I want it to pick an album at random, play the entire album straight through, and then pick another album.

I own Plusar+ and it does not seem to do this.

I'm perfectly happy to pay for it, though I'd like at least a free trial to make sure I find the player useable overall.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out PowerAmp. It comes in Free and Pro versions, and allows you to randomize the album selection, the song selection inside an album, or both.

Comment: For anyone who tries this, I found the terminology a bit confusing: to shuffle albums, play an album, and select 'shuffle categories'. Also, to get the 'next category' buttons, you have to turn on 'Pro Buttons' in the settings for your current skin.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've gotten so used to "Next category" that it escaped me that it wasn't very intuitive at first.

Comment: One more note: The repeat also has to be set to 'advance list'. If you don't have that, it will stop at the end of the album.